# Encoding MKV to DVD with ffmpeg

Tags: conversion, dvd, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert the file type of a movie file so I could burn it on a DVD disc.
Here's the command and output:

```
$ ffmpeg -i "/path/to/movie.mkv" -target dvd "movie.mkv"
FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.1-4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1.2, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1.2 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Sep 16 2011 17:08:44, gcc: 4.4.3

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 47.95 (48000/1001) -> 23.98 (24000/1001)
Input #0, matroska, from '/path/to/movie.mkv':
  Duration: 02:10:21.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x544, PAR 1:1 DAR 40:17, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: dca, 48000 Hz, 5.1, s16
Assuming NTSC for target.
Output #0, dvd, to 'movie.mkv':
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 720x480 [PAR 80:51 DAR 40:17], q=2-31, 6000 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, s16, 448 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
[dvd @ 0x193a690]buffer underflow i=1 bufi=1203 size=1792rate=5595.1kbits/s     
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Error while opening file bitrate=4752.2kbits/s    
$
```

My OS:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS"
$ uname -a
Linux my-desktop 2.6.32-34-generic #77-Ubuntu SMP <omitted> x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As can be seen from the output, ffmpeg stopped converting the file on the last error line.
I've searched google for this and there's a **similar** problem that is a bug, but I'm not sure if this is a bug? If it's a bug - how can I perform the conversion?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the error happened due to lack of space in the HDD...